# How to use adlfs (ffspec) and pyarrow/pandas to download multiple blobs (read_parquet) concurrently with column projection and row filtering

Tags: pandas, filesystems, python-asyncio, parquet, pyarrow

I want to exploit [pyarrow](https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/parquet.html#reading-and-writing-the-apache-parquet-format), [ffspec](https://filesystem-spec.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html) and its Azure FS implementation [adlfs](https://github.com/fsspec/adlfs) in order to download multiple files in parallel. By parallel I mean that the actual IO-bound operation should exploit async/await code to trigger the download of blobs at the same time, and await the download of all blobs at the end.
I also wish to exploit the column projection and row filtering arguments of pandas/pyarrow in order to limit what is actually downloaded so that to limit the network bandwith, associated costs, and a general speed-up.

What I tried so far, using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd
storage_options={"connection_string": "MY_CONNECTION_STRING_EXAMPLE"}
CONTAINER = "MY_CONTAINER_NAME"
FILE = "PATH/TO/FILE.parquet"
FILEPATH = f"az://{CONTAINER}/{FILE}"
# column projection and row filtering example
columns = ["col1", "col2"]
rows = [[("myindex", "<=", pd.Timestamp("2023-11-08 08:00:07")), ("myindex", ">=", pd.Timestamp("2023-11-08 08:00:02"))]]
df = pd.read_parquet(FILEPATH, storage_options=storage_options, columns=columns, filters=rows)
```

Now, what if I have a given list of blobs to download and I wish to download them concurretly? How can I do that w.r.t. performances?

Comment: You can use ParquetDataSet and pass it a list of URL. It will load them in parallel.  https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/generated/pyarrow.parquet.ParquetDataset.html

Comment: @0x26res Thank you for the input. Do you know if pyarrow ParquetDataSet is implemented with asyncio concurrency or with a pool of threads? I would prefer the first one. Also adlfs makes use of Python SDK for Azure Blob Storage which implements the async methods for the I/O of blobs. It would be cool to exploits them with a list of blobs if possible.

Comment: @0x26res pyarrow seems not to have the storage options needed to pass the connection string as credential for the azure cloud. How can I test it with the given snippet of code?

Comment: it should work with azure (`pd.read_parquet` uses arrow under the hood). I think you need to pass it a filesystem. See this https://arrow.apache.org/docs/python/filesystems.html#using-fsspec-compatible-filesystems-with-arrow

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using [Ray Data](https://docs.ray.io/en/latest/data/data.html). It is build upon Apache Arrow supports fsspec including adlfs. Moreover, it is build to parallelize exactly such kind of workloads and much more:

```
    import adlfs
    import ray
    
    fs = adlfs.AzureBlobFileSystem(account_name="azureopendatastorage")
    ds = ray.data.read_parquet(f"az://{CONTAINER}/{FILE}", filesystem=fs)

    print(ds.schema())
    res_dict = ds.take_all()
```